# Is it possible to get data from REST APIs in SpagoBI?

Tags: spagobi

I try to use Tuleap REST API with SpagoBI and it can't find any information.

So, is it possible to get data from REST APIs in SpagoBI?

Thanks for your answer,

Sandra

Comment: I'm also interested in this capability. I suspect it can be accomplished most easily with a script-based soagobi dataset, in groovy. I'm trying the same approach with using a soap based web service as a dataset, since the web-service dataset feature is not adequately documented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  I've spent a while trying to get this working. 
Below is a link with the technique that worked for me.

In short:
I'm using a Script Data-Set, the Groovy language, and the Groovy WSLite web service library. This required updating the version of Groovy shipped with SpagoBI and dropping in the Groovy WSLite library.

1. The Groovy script retrieves any parameters passed
2. Makes the web service calls with the parameters
3. Parses the results
4. Creates the output in SpagoBI's DataSet XML format

[SpagoBI DataSet REST Webservice via Groovy](http://www.davidbharrison.com/spagobi-dataset-rest-webservice-via-groovy/)

```
//Sample code: Using Groovy and Groovy WSLite to call a RESTful web service
//Then, the response is parsed and returned in SpagoBI DataSet's XML format
import wslite.rest.*

def param_ip  = parameters['param_ip'] ?: ''

def client = new RESTClient("http://ip-api.com/json/${param_ip.toString()}")
def response = client.get()    
assert response.statusCode == 200    
def str = response.json

"""
<ROWS>
    <ROW
        params="${parameters['param_ip'].toString()}" 
        status="${str.status.toString()}"
        country="${str.country.toString()}"
        countryCode="${str.countryCode.toString()}"
        region="${str.region.toString()}"
        regionName="${str.regionName.toString()}"
        city="${str.city.toString()}"
        zip="${str.zip.toString()}"
        lat="${str.lat.toString()}"
        lon="${str.lon.toString()}"
        timezone="${str.timezone.toString()}"
        isp="${str.isp.toString()}"
        org="${str.org.toString()}"
        as="${str.as.toString()}"
    />
</ROWS>
""".toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use REST 2.0 API, but you have to have FIWARE version of SpagoBI.
Versions are the same, excpet that FIWARE have REST API services.

Check this links:

http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/data-visualization-spagobi/documentation

and Apiary:
http://docs.spagobi.apiary.io/#reference/0/the-content-subresource/return-the-document-content